# Get Exact Array Key From Duplicate Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this `$combo` array :

```
    Array (
    [0] => 11.3
    [1] => 1.3
    [2] => 1.3
    [3] => 1.3
    )
```

then I try to process that array using foreach loop :

```
foreach ($combo as $value) {
   $key = array_keys($combo, $value);
}
```

the `$key` return unexpected on key 1, 2, 3 because I have duplicate value : 1.3

I want to have exact array key for each value. how to do this?

Comment: [`foreach ($combo as $key => $value)`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: What do you want your result to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See `foreach` on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.
>
> There are two syntaxes:
>
> ```
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
>     statement
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>     statement
> ```

So you can do:

```
foreach ($combo as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; //0, 1, 2, 3 ...
    echo $value; //11.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3 ...
}
```